# Wrong return value when access member of class

Tags: c++, class, member

I have a class Character and two subclasses Warrior and Wizard.

```
class Character {

protected:
std::string m_name;
Weapon m_weapon;
int m_life;

 public:
 virtual void hit(Character& cible);

};

class Warrior : public Character{
 public:
 Warrior(std::string name);
 };

 class Wizard : public Character{
 public:
 Wizard(std::string name);
 };
```

I also have a class Weapon.

```
class Weapon {

protected:
std::string m_name;
int m_damage;
public:
Weapon();
Weapon(std::string name,int damage, int reloading_time);
int get_damage() ;
```

};

The hit function is:

```
void Character::hit(Character &cible){
cible.dec_life(m_weapon.get_damage());
}
```

and get_damage is simply:

```
int Weapon::get_damage() {
return m_damage;
}
```

The problem is that m_weapon.get_damage() returns the value -2 in the hit function for every character (warrior or wizard) even though its Weapon's damage is 10 or 15.

Main:

```
int main()
{
string character_name;
cout << "Warrior 1 : ";
cin >> character_name;
Warrior character_1(character_name);
cout << endl << "Wizard 2 : ";
cin >> character_name;
Wizard character_2(character_name);
character_1.hit(character_2);
}
```

Weapon Constructor:

```
Weapon::Weapon(std::string name,int damage, int reloading_time){
m_name=name;
m_damage=damage;
}
```

Warrior Constructor:

```
Warrior::Warrior(string name){
m_name=name;
m_life=100;
Weapon m_weapon("Rusted Axe",5,0);
cout << endl << "Warrior " << m_name <<" created." <<endl;
}
```

Wizard Constructor :

```
Wizard::Wizard(string name){
m_name=name;
m_mana=100;
m_life=100;
Weapon m_weapon("Apprentice Wand",10,0);
cout << endl <<"Wizard " << m_name <<" created."<<endl;


}
```

Any idea where I get it wrong?

Comment: Do you set m_damage to something other than -2?

Comment: what does the Weapon constructor look like and when do you set it on the character?

Comment: Can you post your main function?

Comment: Need to post more, relevant code.

Comment: [Seems like it works to me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7219f2768f67ddb)

Comment: Do you call Weapon() or Weapon(string, int, int) when constructing the character? I don't see where damage is specified.

Comment: I call Weapon(string, int,int).
Here's the constructor of Warrior :

Warrior::Warrior(string name){
m_name=name;
m_life=100;
Weapon m_weapon("Rusted Axe",5,0);
cout << endl << "Warrior " << m_name <<" created." <<endl;

}

Comment: @user2744550: This code constructs a local object `m_weapon`, which has no relation to class member `m_weapon`. You can't do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere in your code I see numbers `10` and `15`. How do you expect the program to know that specific weapon's damage is supposed to be `10` or `15`?

According to your code, class `Weapon` has a constructor that accepts the weapon's damage value. But you never use this constructor. Instead, you seem to be constructing `m_weapon` members using the default constructor of `Weapon` class, which simply leaves garbage in `m_damage` field.

You have to develop a way to perform a meaningful initialization of your `m_weapon` objects. At this point you seem to be hoping that the compiler somehow telepathically figures out the damage values for various weapon objects. Compilers cannot do that.

**EDIT:** What you do in your constructors is just construct a *local* `m_weapon` object, which has absolutely no relation to member `m_weapon` object. Your member `m_weapon` objects remain uninitialized (i.e. default initialized with garbage in `m_damage`). It is not possible to perform initialization of member subobject from a constructor body. Member subobjects can only be initialized from constructor initializer list (read about it in your C++ book or do a search). On top of that, you are only allowed to initialize *immediate* members of the class, meaning that `m_weapon` can only be initialized from `Character`'s constructor. It is not possible to do it from `Warrior`'s or `Wizard`'s constructor.

Comment: The numbers 10 qnd 5 are used in the Warrior and Wizard constructors.
I edited the OP with both constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor in your `Character` class under **protected** section, like this one:

```
Character::Character(std::string& name, Weapon& weapon)
:    m_name(name),
     m_weapon(weapon)
{}
```

Then in you Warrior and Wizard constructor do this:

```
Warrior::Warrior(std::string& name)
:    Character(name, Weapon("Rusted Axe",5,0))
{
    m_life=100;
    cout << endl << "Warrior " << m_name <<" created." <<endl;
}

Wizard::Wizard(std::string& name)
:    Character(name, Weapon("Rusted Axe",5,0))
{
    m_life=100;
    cout << endl << "Wizard " << m_name <<" created." <<endl;
}
```